# How to connect flutter app to PHP server?

Tags: php, flutter, mobile, server, backend

I have made somewhat complicated web applications in PHP in the past and now I want to develop PHP server-side scripts to connect an application interface made with flutter to my server/host.

I don't know any flutter and I'm not interested in learning it. Is there a simple way to send requests from the application to my PHP scripts and back to the end-user without the need to learn flutter? if so how? What is the equivalent of AJAX or form submission in there? Or are there completely different technologies?

Any form of guidance would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: There is no way to do this without learning flutter.

Comment: what parts of flutter would I need to know? any specific technologies or functions?

Comment: You need to know the dart programming language basics, the flutter http library, and some UI widgets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create your backend as a [REST API](https://restfulapi.net/) in PHP and provide endpoints that can be hit by your Flutter application.
You could return response in [JSON](https://www.json.org/) or XML format from your PHP REST API which can be manipulated at the application front-end with flutter.

Comment: I'll think about that. Thanks